# Magento URL key including / redirect to 404

Tags: magento-enterprise, url-rewrite, product-urls, magento-1.14, url-key

I would like to generate url keys with '/' of products. I have override the `\Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey::beforeSave` method and generated url key as per requirement.

My before save method is :

```
public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();

        if ($object->getIsDuplicate()) {
            $object = $this->_generateNextUrlKeySuffix($object);
        }
        $brandLong = $object->getData('brand_long');
        $collection = $object->getData('collection');
        $urlKey = $object->formatUrlKey($brandLong).'/'.$object->formatUrlKey($collection).'/'.$object->formatUrlKey($object->getData('sku'));
        if (empty($urlKey)) {
            $object->setData($attributeName, $object->formatUrlKey($object->getName()));
            $object = $this->_generateNextUrlKeySuffix($object);
        } elseif (!empty($urlKey) && !$object->getIsDuplicate()) {
            $object->setData($attributeName, $urlKey);
        }

        $this->_validateEntityUrl($object);
        return $this;
    }
```

But generated url keys redirecting to 404.Url key is as below

`attribute1-value/attribute2/sku`

It redirecting to 404

Comment: Please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244801/the-new-url-key-is-not-working-for-product-page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can reference something such as this: https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento-FilterUrls